# Solving for a Jacobian of a composite function given gradients

Tags: partial-derivative, jacobian

We are given the following:

> Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are differentiable. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $b = f(a)$. If $\nabla f_1(a)=(2,-1)$ , $\nabla f_2(a)=(-3,-1)$ , $\nabla g_1(b)=(-1,0)$ , $\nabla g_2(b)=(1,-3)$, then find $J(g \circ f)$.

Currently, I have reasoned, and correct me if I'm wrong, that the Jacobian Matrix will be as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\\ 1 & -3\end{pmatrix}$$

I solved this by just using the gradient of g, which seems rather simple, so I'm not confident. Does anyone have a hint if this is indeed incorrect?

Comment: It is incorrect. You need to use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule) for $g\circ f$

Comment: Use $J(g\circ f)(a)=Jg(b)\cdot Jf(a)$

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @janmarqz how would you pull out information from the gradient if we aren't given equations for $a$ or $b$

Comment: you already have the matrices $Jg(b)$ and $Jf(a)$ so you have to multiply them to get $J(g\circ f)(a)$